# H0w have group theory and fractal geometry been combined?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, fractals, geometric-group-theory

Has there been a significant tie made between group theory and fractal geometry? What are some ways that they have been tied together?
I've been inspired to ask this question by [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg) image of a free group.

[image]

Comment: This google search will lead you to one class of examples: ["Fuchsian group" Hausdorff](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fuchsian+group%22+Hausdorff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of connections in geometric group theory, which studies things like free groups. Every hyperbolic group (an infinite group with a special condition) has a space at infinity that is either a sphere or a fractal. For instance, the free group has a cantor set at infinity. Other groups have Sierpinski curves and Menger sponges.

Space-filling curves also arise in hyperbolic geometry (see the Cannon-Thurston map).

Finally, most fractals can be generated using the ring structure of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This space is called the *boundary* of the hyperbolic groups, and you can kinda think of it as the boundary of the Cayley graph (the groups being hyperbolic kinda means the Cayley graphs look like your typical Escher painting, which kinda have a boundary). Kinda.

Comment: See http://vimeo.com/4188373# for a pretty picture of this.

Answer (score 4):

See the book [Indra's pearls](http://klein.math.okstate.edu/IndrasPearls/) by Mumford, Series and Wright for the [wonders of Kleinian Groups](http://www.josleys.com/galleries.php?catid=7).